# Нужна ли запятая поле слов "благодаря своим достижениям"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, обстоятельственный-оборот

Благодаря своим достижением, компания Emmerre по праву занимает одну из лидирующих позиций на европейском рынке запчастей для грузовых автомобилей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Запятую лучше не ставить, так как оборот тесно связан с тем, что описано далее:

> Благодаря своим достижени**ям** компания Emmerre по праву занимает одну из лидирующих позиций на европейском рынке запчастей для грузовых автомобилей.

Answer (score 1):

"Благодаря" в этом предложении выступает в роли производного предлога со значением причины.

Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (***благодаря***, вопреки, ввиду, в целях, в связи с, во избежание, вследствие...), **обособляются при подчеркивании их смысла.**
[Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=51)

Это самый обычный оборот (довольно часто используемый, с самым обычным значением, без особого распространения и акцента на причинах), стоящий в начале предложения, — он не нуждается в отделении запятой от общего текста.

***Благодаря своим научным достижениям*** чеченцы ещё прославятся на весь мир (Р. Кадыров); ***Благодаря своим достижениям*** Neher входит в число примерно 250 представительских торговых марок Германии, которые... (из статьи); ***Благодаря своим достижениям и личным качествам*** она является легендой мирового спорта (о Вере Чаславской).

P. S. [Достиже́ние](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (ед. ч.) — достижения (мн. ч.) — достижени**ям** (чему? Д. п.).